# Неправильное добавление в бд

Tags: php, mysql

Добавление в базу данных происходит, если писать значения в values, а считывание из ячеек не происходит. Что нужно писать в `Values`?

`mySQL_query("insert into Gefest1 (id,model,color,massa,price) values ();`

Сам код добавления:

```
<div id="content">

 <?

 $x=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
if (!$x) die ("error#1");
$y=mysql_select_db("Gefest");
if (!$y) die ("error#2");

$q=mysql_query("select*from `Gefest1`");

echo('<table border="1" >');
?>
<tr>
<img src="3.jpg" width="1000" height="300">         
<tr><td><font size="6">номер</font></td><td><font size="6">модель</font></td><td><font size="6">цвет</font></td><td><font size="6">масса</font></td><td><font size="6">цена</font></td></tr>
</tr>

<form action='do.html' method='post'><br>
номер   &nbsp           <input type='int' name='txt[0]' value=''><br>
модель                      <input type='text' name='txt[1]' value=''><br>
цвет  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp      <input type='text' name='txt[2]' value=''><br>
масса   &nbsp&nbsp          <input type='int' name='txt[3]' value=''><br>
цена   &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp     <input type='int' name='txt[4]' value=''>

</form>
<?
if(@$_GET["action"]=="add")
{

    mySQL_query("insert into Gefest1 (id,model,color,massa,price) values ();
}
while ($d=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{

?>

<tr>

        <td><font size="5"><?echo($d["id"]);?></font></td>
        <td><font size="5"><?echo($d["model"]);?></font></td>
        <td><font size="5"><?echo($d["color"]);?></font></td>
        <td><font size="5"><?echo($d["massa"]);?></font></td>
        <td><font size="5"><?echo($d["price"]);?></font></td>

</tr>

<?
}
echo('</table>');           
?>

<a href="?action=add">Добавить</a>
<?
```

Comment: Так вы сделайте дамп (`var_dump/var_export/print_r`) того, что приходит, и увидите, что именно вам надо вставить в ваш INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@CAHEK](/users/26106/cahek)](/users/26106/cahek), вы сами процитировали проблемную строчку:

```
mySQL_query("insert into Gefest1 (id,model,color,massa,price) values ();
```

Посмотрите, в чем ваша ошибка:

```
if(@$_GET["action"]=="add")
{   
    /**
     * Имена функций регистрозависимы. mysql_query и mySQL_query — не одно и то же
     * Еще у вас ошибка синтаксиса, пропущено след. выражение: __");__
     * Из-за этого все, вплоть до ?> считается частью незакрытой строки
     */
    mysql_query("insert into Gefest1 (id,model,color,massa,price) values ();");
}
```

Все данные, пришедшие из формы, у вас хранятся в переменной `$_GET['txt']`;

```
$data = $_GET['txt'];
//$data[0] - номер
//$data[1] - модель
//$data[2] - цвет
//$data[3] - масса
//$data[4] - цена
```

Их вам и нужно сначала проверить и только потом вставлять в базу данных.
Плюс учитывайте, используя `mysql_query`, что:

> Данное расширение устарело, начиная с
> версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в
> будущем. Используйте вместо него
> MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.